# check integer constants have different values at compilation time

Tags: c++, compilation

My question is the following. I have a large number of static const integers that work as Identifiers. For this reason I would like to know if it is possible to check at compilation time if there is more than one constant with the same value (some kind of static assert...).

I do not want to use an enum as these constants are defined in different modules and I don't want to have like a very long enum with all of them (and some of them are not related to each other).

Here you have a basic example:

```
// module: foo.h
const uint32_t ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_X = 46;
const uint32_t ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_Y = 51;
...

// module: boo.h
const uint32_t ELEMENT_TYPE_BOO_C = 21;
const uint32_t ELEMENT_TYPE_BOO_D = 51;
```

error: ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_Y and ELEMENT_TYPE_BOO_D have the same value.

I'm not an expert at all and the only thing that comes to my mind to detect this error is template specialization.

```
template<uint32_t N>
struct element_traits {
};

template<ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_X> {
    enum { value = ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO };
};
```

But it seems to be a complex solution. I don't know if there is a more elegant/better solution. I haven't found anything so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a good old-fashioned search through the codebase?

Comment: Do the constants have *anything* in common that allows you to handle them?

Comment: Luchian Grigore: what do you mean by "search through the codebase"?

Comment: Kerrek SB: apart from the type, they do not have anything else in common.

Comment: Can you change the type from `uint32_t` to something like `class my_id_type`? If so, you can probably find a way to do this using template recursion.

Comment: you could write something that creates an error when the template argument is 0, and pass CONST_A-CONST_B as the template parameter of a global instance

Comment: Add a build step where you grep your headers for these definitions and parse the list to check for duplicates. Any reasonable solution that I can think of with C++ requires you to list all the identifiers you want to check for duplicates.

Comment: tenfour, could you give me an example on that?
Gir, I don't follow you...do I have to sub all the possible combinations?

Comment: Why isn't a runtime test acceptable?  It is easy to make the test deterministic and run right at the start of the program...

Comment: Do the numbers have to be fixed, or would it be OK to generate them at startup?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it actually at compile-time without drastically changing your syntax and/or potentially slowing compilation drastically, and certainly making un-maintable code. I would go with a runtime check if you are really concerned. But... your IDs actually do have something in common; they share the same integer space. So I think putting them in a big enum is not a bad idea.

Comment: I thought you only wanted to compare 2 constants. otherwise ,using my suggestion,you would need to compare them all . which is worse than what you suggested

Comment: @user1192525 What kind of solution are you looking for? Do you think it would be reasonable if you had to make a list of all the variables you want to check for uniqueness?

Comment: Keith Randall, of course doing it a runtime is acceptable but I'd be even nicer to do it at runtime. I'm just wondering if there is a elegant way for doing this. If not, I'll perform the check at runtime.

Comment: @eq, doing a list of all the constants is like defining an enum with all of them. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would. How would you check the values at run time without listing them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could certainly do this using macros:

```
#define UNIQUE_CONSTANT(variable, value) \
  const uint32_t variable = value; \
  bool constant_val_##value = value;
```

Then you will get a multiple definition error if the same value is used twice.

(Technically, this will detect the error at link time, not compile time.)

Comment: Not a bad idea. But there is an unnecessary increase in memory consumption (like my solution). If I cannot find something else I think I'll choose for checking the values at runtime.

Comment: One byte per constant doesn't seem like that big a memory footprint.  And if your linker is good, those extra variables are never referenced and can be removed from the final executable.

Comment: This seems nice.  If you replace that third line with `struct unique_id_##value {}` there should be no memory footprint.  You're simply declaring an unused, empty data structure.

Comment: the only concern is that using this macro inside different namespaces won't work :d

Comment: That and the value isn't case sensetive. 0xFFEF != 0xffef != 65519

Answer (score 0):

Based on Keith's solution. I could "check" constants have unique value for debug build and skip it for release build.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEFINE_UNIQUE_CONSTANT(variable, value) \
    const uint32_t variable = value;            \
    uint32_t constant_val_##value = value;
#else
#define DEFINE_UNIQUE_CONSTANT(variable, value) \
    const uint32_t variable = value;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If large number of constants must be different and must be defined in different source files then you could generate them that way e.g., start with a file that contains filenames and corresponding constant names and generate the rest at each build.

Input file:

```
[foo.h]
ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_X
ELEMENT_TYPE_FOO_Y

[boo.h]
ELEMENT_TYPE_BOO_C
ELEMENT_TYPE_BOO_D
```

The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from itertools import count

config = SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.optionxform = lambda x: x # use names as-is
config.read('input.cfg')

counter = count(1)
for filename in config.sections():
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
         for (name, _), i in zip(config.items(filename), counter):
             f.write("const uint32_t %s = %s;\n" % (name, i))
```